# sort products from <option> tag using Django and HTML

Tags: django, django-views

I have a list like

```
<select class="selection-2" name="sorting">
    <option>Default Sorting</option>
    <option>Popularity</option>
    <option>Price: low to high</option>
    <option>Price: high to low</option>
</select>
```

Now i want to sort the products which i have listed to my html page using Django View.

```
def product_list(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
    paginator = Paginator(products, 9)
    page =  request.GET.get('page')
    products = paginator.get_page(page) 

    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        products = Product.objects.filter(category=category)
    context = {
        'category': category,
        'categories': categories,
        'products': products
    }

return render(request, 'shop/product/list.html', context)
```

This is my product list view and i want to create a view for the sorting and filtering of the products.

By doing this i want to apply filters to my product list and sort them in price "Low to High" Or "High to Low" order.

For this i have created a filter view

```
def filter(request):
    try:  
        q = request.GET.get('')
        print(q)
    except:
        q = None
    if q:
        products = Product.objects.filter(price__range=(price1,price2))
        context = {'query': q, 'products': products}    
        template = 'shop/product/result.html'
    else:
        context = {'query': q}      
        template = 'shop/product/list.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

In this do i need to create form to post the results to my "Product_list" view.

Comment: What are you looking for? The Query to achieve this?

Comment: You can use template filter dictsort if you want sort in html [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-dictsort](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-dictsort)

Comment: you mean a table where you have dynamic filter and acending/descending filters?

Comment: There are a lot of options provided online for these use cases. What have you tried so far regarding that?

Comment: Please have a look at my code.It's not complete right now.